# string replace (php)

Tags: php, regex

Can anyone suggest a quick function that will automatically strip spaces & apostrophes from a string in PHP.

I am just need to remove any unwanted stuff from a string before it is used as an email address.

eg.

```
$email = "myname's@site.com  "; // need to remove the apostrope & empty space
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$email = str_replace(array("'", ' '), '', $email);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
echo preg_replace('/[\\\' ]/', '', "myname's@site.com ");
```

But I don't believe this is the propper thing to do. Consider something like this:

```
if(!filter_var("myname's@site.com ", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    echo("E-mail is not valid");
```

Comment: Wow.. awesome response thank you guys (and girls) cannot be sexist :-)

Comment: Thanks! Also consider the second snippet, because emails can be malformed in so many different ways you cannot predict all of them. It is better to inform user about wrong e-mail or deleting it from the database if you have it already stored.

Comment: @Gaz: Also consider ticking the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is not str_replace but validation for an email address (what you're describing is actually sanitizing, but wouldn't you want to block the input if the email address is not valid?).

Here's (an example of) a regular expression to check the format of an email address:

```
( preg_match( '/^\w[-.\w]*@(\w[-._\w]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}.*)$/', $_POST['email'] )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$email = "myname's@site.com ";
$email = preg_replace("/['\s]/", '', $email);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/LWkJrQmP)

Answer (score 1):

```
$remove = array(" ", "'");
$email = str_replace($remove, "", $email);
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Sorry - i keep forgetting to tick stuff :-) they all work but i've ticked the one i used in the end. Thanks guys much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$email = preg_replace("/(\s|')/", '', "myname's@site.com ");
```